# Issues in the proof of $E_{TM}$ is Turing reducible to $A_{TM}$

Tags: computability, reductions, undecidability

First definition:

> $A_{TM}$ = $\{ <M,w> | $M is a TM and M on w accepts$ \}$

Second definition:

> $E_{TM} = \{ <M> |$ M is a TM and L(M) = $\phi \}$

Let $T^{A_{TM}}$ be an oracle Turing machine with an oracle $A_{TM}$. We want to show that $E_{TM}$ is Turing reducible to $A_{TM}$.

$T^{A_{TM}}$ = "On input $<M>$, where M is a TM:

1. Construct a TM N:

> 1. N = "On any input:
> 2. For i=0, 1, 2, 3. Run M on s_i for i steps
>    where $s_i \in \Sigma^*$ and $\Sigma^*=\{s_0, s_1, s_2, .... \}$.
> 3. If M
>    accepts any of these strings, then accept."

2. Ask the oracle: Is $<N, 0> \in A_{TM}$.
3. If the oracle answers NO, accept. If YES, reject."

Now, Sipser said in pp. 236-237, "If M's language isn't empty, N will accept every input and in particular, input 0. Hence the oracle will answer YES, and $T^{A_{TM}}$ will reject. Conversely, if M's language is empty, $T^{A_{TM}}$ will accept."

My question: Why N will accept every input and in particular, input 0? It is not clear how N will accept every string. For example, M will run on all input of $\Sigma^*$ but only those strings that are in L(M) will be accepted and I don't understand how N will accept every input. Moreover, it is not clear why he choose string "0".

Note that I changed step 2 where Sipser wrote: "Run M in parallel on all strings in $\Sigma^*$" since as I believe mean the same thing unless you have something to say.

Answer (score 4):

First, note that Sipser says ""If **M's** language isn't empty, **N** will accept every input".

---

Let us first prove this statement:
Assume $L(M) \neq \emptyset$.

Then there exists some $x \in L(M)$. Because $L(M) \subseteq \Sigma^*$  we have $x \in  \Sigma^*$. Then because $s_i \in \Sigma^*$ and $\Sigma^*=\{s_0, s_1, s_2, .... \}$, there exists an $i^*$ such that $s_{i^*} = x$.

The TM $N$ accepts "if M accepts any of these strings". Because $s_{i^*}$ is one of these strings, $N$ accepts.

---

Note that $N$ never considered *its own input*! It only decides whether to accept or not based on $M$ which is part of the TM $N$ itself, *not* $N$'s input.

The string 0 is totally arbitrary. You can pick any string because we know that $N$ will accept *any* string if and only if* the language of $M$ is not empty. Because we want to reduce to $T^{A_{TM}}$ this is indeed all we care for.

<sub>* The other direction remains to be shown for a complete proof.</sub>

Comment: Thank you Idmean, so If M's language isn't empty, it does accept only those strings that are membership of L(M) but not all strings of $\Sigma^*$ (since in Sipser's words that says N will accept every input means to me that L(M) = $\Sigma^*$).

Comment: Now, you said that N accepts if M accepts any of these strings (the strings that are in L(M) but not all strings in $\Sigma^*$). Now, how this would imply "N will accept any string iff language of M is not empty"?

Comment: Maybe his phrasing is confusing, but Sipser certainly didn't mean to imply $L(M) = \Sigma^*$. Concerning "N will accept any string iff language of M is not empty": I proved the forward direction in the answer. Is there something unclear about the proof itself? Or are you asking about the other direction?

Comment: Another hint that may clear up some confusion: Consider again that $N$ never uses its input in any way. It doesn't even need to read it.

Comment: Yes, I have a question. For example, why we choose string 0? Suppose M is a TM that decides all strings that are starting with 1. Now L(M) = {1, 10, 11, 100, ...}. Now If we plug this M into $T^{A_{TM}}$, then $T^{A_{TM}}$ in step 2 will say No, since N on input 0 doesn't accept (reject/loop). This imply that the oracle will return NO. Therefore, $T^{A_{TM}}$ accepts. This means that M's language is empty. Now can you tell me what went wrong?

Comment: $N$ will indeed accept in your example. $N$ accepts if $M$ accepts *any* $s_i \in \Sigma^*$. Clearly the $L(M)$ you defined is a subset of $\Sigma^*$ so there exists (in fact multiple) $s_i$ on which $M$ accepts. Therefore $N$ accepts. $N$ does not consider it's input. It doesn't matter whether you give $N$ 0, 1, or 1111. $N$ accepts its own input if and only if $M$ accepts some string, i.e. $L(M) \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127290/discussion-between-user777-and-idmean).